# Lists in Dart (Flutter)

Tags: list, dart

So Im learning Dart right now, and I have a problem when it comes to declare lists.
In a tutorial I saw that the teacher declared a list by using this syntax:

```
void main() {
final names = ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz'];
}
```

And in another turorial I saw this:

```
void main() {
List<String> names = ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz'];
}
```

I want to know if there is a differance between the two.

And thank you guys for reading my question

Answer (score 3):

`final` just means that once assigned it can't be reassigned. So you can't do

```
final names = ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz'];
names = ['Foo2', 'Bar2', 'Baz2'];
```

You could add it also to the other one as well like

```
final List<String> names = ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz'];
```

Without final it's fine to do

```
List<String> names = ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz'];
names = ['Foo2', 'Bar2', 'Baz2'];
```

Furthermore it's usually okay to leave out the type, because the compiler is smart enough to see that it is in fact a `List<String>` in this case. If you want to make a non-final variable without indicating the type you can use the keyword `var`, like

```
var names = ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz'];
```

So in these examples

```
var names = ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz'];
List<String> names = ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz'];
```

are identical, and

```
final names = ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz'];
final List<String> names = ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz'];
```

are identical.

Answer (score -2):

First one is the List which can be use as dynamic list or you can use as

```dart
List<dynamic> name= ['one,'two','three'];
```

Where as second one is used for specific String List OR

```dart
List<int> numbers= [1,2,3];
```